# Resolving error dataLayer is not defined

Tags: google-tag-manager

I have created Google Tag Manager data layer variable and published the container. When I access the page I get the error in Chrome console

```
dataLayer is not defined
```

The datalayer push script is in the the HEAD element and the GTM code snippet is in the Body tag.

Comment: Are you trying to do a `dataLayer.push` without having first defined the dataLayer? Let's see your code...

Comment: The datalayer push script is in the the HEAD element and the GTM code snippet is in the Body tag.

Comment: OK, but what does it look like? Are you doing a `window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || []`?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

If you are trying to use the dataLayer, you need to make sure it is defined before you use it:

```
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
window.dataLayer.push({
   'someKey': 'someValue'
})

// GTM Container here
```

Comment: I don't think this is any good. If you don't have the dataLayer, probably something about the gtm didn't load. This way you push to some array that no one reads from.

Answer (score 0):

the best way we can do for undefined datalayer error is,
put it in conditions like,-

```
window && window.dataLayer && window.dataLayer.push({data:data});
```

hope this will helpful:)